# Align a texted section on the left and keep it centered in bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have some issue in `bootstrap-4`. 
I centered the  section with `text-center`:

```
<div class="text-center text-left">
    <h2>Hi,I'm,</h2>
    <h2>Bonheur jed,</h2>
    <h2>Web Developer.</h2>
</div>
```

but i don't need the headings to center

```
                     Hi,I'm,
                  Bonheur jed,
                 Web Developer.
```

instead, i want them to  align on the left but centered

```
                 Hi,I'm,
                 Bonheur jed,
                 Web Developer.
```

Comment: why are you used in this both   `text-center`  `text-left`

Comment: float left fixed it thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should remove `text-center` and put `text-left`

if you want to section center ,you must write some `css`  for your `div` class 
example class="mydiv" and added some css  you want to alignment

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="text-left">
           <h2>Hi,I'm,</h2>
           <h2>Bonheur jed,</h2>
           <h2>Web Developer.</h2>
    </div>
```